# How do I match a non-word pattern only if it is not immediately followed by a specific character

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match `\w+,\w+` expressions unless immediately followed by `(`

So, to give an example, I am looking for a regex that matches expressions like

`X_11,A` and `Y,C_A` but **not** `XNR,B` and `Y,A` in strings like

`X_11,A+0.7*Y,A(-12)-0.3(XNR,B(-1)-Y,C_A)`

I tried various solutions suggested in related posts that use negative lookaheads. But in the best case only the last term `Y,C_A` is matched (via `(\w*,\w*)(?!.*\()`), but obviously that one looks too far ahead for the earlier terms. The straightforward `(\w*,\w*)(?!\()` still captures `XNR,`, which I don't want. I have also tried more complicated solutions. They seem to exploit specific features of the problem, for example that there is only one term of interest per line, constant substrings, word boundaries, etc. These don't appear to apply to mine. What am I missing?

Comment: Use `\w+,\w+(?![(\w])` or `\w+,\w+\b(?!\()`

Comment: Both work. Thanks!